# What is the meaning of |H(jw)| concerning the transfer function

Tags: filter

Noob question here but my books talks about the magnitude of the transfer function |H(jw)| a lot but I don't understand the meaning of |H(jw)| itself.  Because of this I can't interpret the meaning of Bode plots of filters as it is the Y-axis of these Bode plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transfer function takes a complex number input (or in this case, pure imaginary \$j \omega\$), and produces a complex number output.

The "magnitude" of \$H\$ is simply the complex absolute value:

\begin{gather}
|H(j \omega)| = \sqrt{\mathrm{real}(H(j \omega))^2 + \mathrm{imag}(H(j \omega))^2}
\end{gather}

As far as a physical meaning, consider an input signal with an amplitude \$V_0\$ and frequency \$\omega\$. \$H(j \omega)\$ "transforms" this input signal into an output signal, with final amplitude \$V_1 = |H(j \omega)| V_0\$, but it also can shift the phase of the output signal with respect to the input signal.

To summarize, the two plots of the Bode plot are:

1. \$|H(j \omega)|\$, which tells you the ratio of input and output amplitudes (the "gain", or "attenuation")
2. \$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\mathrm{imag}(H(j \omega))}{\mathrm{real}(H(j \omega))}\right)\$, which tells you the phase shift (**note**: this formulation is only accurate in the 1st quadrant; see [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) for the definition which extends to the entire complex plane).

Answer (score 0):

\$H(j\omega)\$ is a complex number, say, \$a+jb\$, where \$a\$ and \$b\$ are functions of frequency, \$\omega\$. The magnitude of the complex number, \$\sqrt {a^2+b^2}\$, is the gain of the transfer function at \$\omega \: rad\:s^{-1}\$. And the phase angle at \$\omega \:rad\:s^{-1}\$ is: \$arctan\large \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\$